# Elasticsearch - mappings VS mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I am new to ElasticSearch. I am looking at some index file definitions and ran across the word "mappings" and "mapping", as seen below. I searched all around elasticsearch's documentation site and found both words referred to a bit, but never an explicit explanation about the difference. is "mappings" just a plural of "mapping", and they accept the same parameters? is the singular mapping different since it's nested in the "dynamic_templates" scope? This seems to be the case, but i can't find anything in documentation to confirm this. thanks

```
 { <--- top level
      ...some JSON...
      "mappings": { //<--- plural
        "_doc": {
          "dynamic_templates": [
            {
              "space": {
                "match_mapping_type": "string",
                "match": "space",
                "mapping": { <--- singular!
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 64,
                  "fields": {
                    "analyzed": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "analyzer": "english"
                    }
                  }
                  ...more JSON...
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `mappings` occurence is the structure where you can define your mapping types. Historically, one was allowed to define several mappings types in a single index, but since the [great mapping refactoring](https://www.elastic.co/blog/great-mapping-refactoring) only one mapping type is allowed. So that's why `mappings`is in the plural form. It will soon disappear.

The second `mapping` is simply a keyword when defining [dynamic field templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html). The `match*` part simply identifies the dynamic field and the `mapping` part defines the mapping for that field. It's kind of an advanced feature, so don't worry if you don't grasp it immediately.